# missing resource bundle exception in java using weblogic

Tags: xsd, jaxb, pojo, xjc, jaxp

I have a requirement that I need to convert xsd file to POJO files. While using tomcat I didnot face any issue but when I am using weblogic I am getting error

> Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResouceBundle,key JAXPSupportedProperty

```
    File tmpDir = util.createTempPOJODirectory();

    String xsdFilePath = convertToXSD(xmlResponse, tmpDir); // The xml response will be converted to XML file and then converted to XSD file

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(xsdFilePath)) {

        log("XSD location ::" + xsdFilePath + " and output location :: " + tmpDir);

        // Setup schema compiler
        SchemaCompiler sc = XJC.createSchemaCompiler();
        sc.forcePackageName("");

        // Setup SAX InputSource
        File schemaFile = new File(xsdFilePath);
        InputSource is = new InputSource(schemaFile.toURI().toString());
        // is.setSystemId(schemaFile.getAbsolutePath());

        // Parse & build
        sc.parseSchema(is);

        log("after parsing and building");

        log("sc :: " + sc);

        S2JJAXBModel model = null;

        try {
            model = sc.bind();
        }
        catch (Exception e1) {

            log("Exception :: " + ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e1));
        }

        log("model :: " + model);

        try {
            JCodeModel jCodeModel = model.generateCode(null, null);

            jCodeModel.build(tmpDir);

            log("generation POJO's is success");
            return "POJO are created under " + tmpDir + " successfully.";
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            log("unable to generate POJO's");
            log("IOException occurs :: " + ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log("Exception occurs :: " + ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
        }`
```

For this I have used below jars :-

- xsd-gen-0.2.1.jar
- xom-1.2.5.jar
- wiztools-commons-lib-0.4.1.jar
- jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar
- jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar
- cli-7.jar

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I have resolved this issue by removing jaxb jars.